# Which is more conducting - molten sodium chloride or molten magnesium chloride?

Tags: ions, conductivity

Which is more conducting - molten sodium chloride or molten magnesium chloride?

I'm pretty sure I know the answer to this but my problem is putting into words. Magnesium is more conductive due to its 2+ charge, and the $\ce{NaCl}$ having a neutral charge. Right?

Would I be right in saying that as the compounds are heating up and melting the ions break away from each other and the ratio of ions in $\ce{MgCl2}$ is 2:1 so therefore the solution would be more highly charged than that of the $\ce{NaCl}$?

I know I'm on the right track, just struggling to explain it.

Comment: The solution is not charged; it is neutral, since it contains equally many positive and negative charges. Also, you don't have any solution at all. Other than that, you may or may not be right. True, $\ce{Mg^2+}$ has greater charge than $\ce{Na+}$, so what?